# SQL Server trigger showing "asynchronous" behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm currently using this trigger in SQL server. Out of 16,000 orders, this is working 99.9% of the time. I've noticed that 0.1% of the time I get orders where the trigger does not run correctly and the `UPDATE` to the `stock` isn't made. I *think* what's happening is that the operation is getting locked while trying to find all the tables in the `INNER JOIN` and moves on to the second `UPDATE` operation while it's waiting for the first one to finish. It updates the `stock_adjusted` to 1 then comes back to the first `UPDATE` but now that `stock_adjusted` is 1 it no longer qualifies for the `WHERE` clause and doesn't update the `stock`. The delay was added to try and address the "async" issue.

I've read that SQL server is synchronous so I'm wondering if such a thing is even possible?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[adjustStock] 
   ON  [dbo].[payment] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    -- run query to adjust stock on product
    UPDATE product WITH(ROWLOCK)
    SET stock = stock - item.qty
    FROM product
        INNER JOIN item ON product.id = item.product
        INNER JOIN cart WITH(NOLOCK) ON item.cart = cart.id
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON cart.id = i.cart
    WHERE item.stock_adjusted = 0 AND
        product.open_box = 1;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

    -- mark line item as stock adjusted
    UPDATE item
    SET item.stock_adjusted = 1
    FROM item
        INNER JOIN cart WITH(NOLOCK) ON item.cart = cart.id
        INNER JOIN product ON item.product = product.id
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON cart.id = i.cart
    WHERE item.stock_adjusted = 0 AND
        product.open_box = 1;

END
```

Comment: A `TRIGGER` with a `NOLOCK`? That is a *very* dangerous choice of a table hint. I am not surprised you are having problems.

Comment: Also, no, T-SQL statements/batches don't (and never do) run asynchronously. Each statement is run in order, and the prior statement must be complete before the next can start.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not too keen on this myself but why shouldn't triggers use `NOLOCK`?

Comment: You're better off [reading](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) about the problems it causes.

Comment: You are more than likely increasing your blocking and potential for deadlocks by putting in a waitfor statement.

Comment: I guess the simple question here is that the logic doesn't seem to make sense: if two triggers run even independently of each other, then the first updates `item.stock_adjusted` to 1, and the second then runs and ignores those `item` rows. I thin you should remove the `where` from the first `update`. You may also need some kind of aggregation of the `inserted` table (and perhaps others) depending on the relationships. `WAITFOR DELAY` in a trigger is really silly, and will just make things worse